# Exact address of a place given its latitude and longitude

Tags: go, google-places-api

I'm developing a web app wherein I need to get the "exact" address given a latitude and longitude pair. I tried Maps Geocode API as well but it doesn't give the exact address. I think Places API would be a good option alas I don't get how to use it.

I'm using golang.

Answer (score 4):

IMO, if you think that reverse geocoding results a bad, Places API results wouldn't make you happier.

Here is the sample of Places API

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=55.753720,37.620144&key=google_map_api_key`

And Geocoder to compare

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=55.753720,37.620144`

As you can see, there is no address in Places API results. The first addresses you may get only after addition `radius` parameter:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=55.753720,37.620144&radius=100&key=google_map_api_key`

For me, trying to decide which address within 100 meters is right is more complex task than simple use of the best possible result from geocoding.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What's the most accurate way to do what I want?

Comment: @YounisShah there is no "accurate way" to do this. You are limited by Google databases in both cases. Just in the case of Geocoder, you use all available addresses DB that returns you closest address. And in the case of Places API, you use Points of Interest database. So if your coordinates pointing to the simple house without shops, museums and gas stations, Places API will return you nothing. Geocoder API may return nothing too (for many small non-US towns it doesn't have address data), but the chance of this result is lower than for Places API.